# how come first layer of conv net alway learn to detect edges first?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

as the title implies the most of my intention, i am really curious about the learning process of conv net that always learn to detect edges at first layer without initialising the weights (filter) or maybe it does??

can anyone explain why always first layer or filters learned to detect edges first in convnet?

Thanks in advance!